# Workflows have stopped creating tasks

Tags: workflow

All my workflows in one site and all its subsites have stopped creating tasks. The workflow starts, I get an email saying tasks will be generated, but no tasks are generated. I can see this from the workflow status. They did work before, and suddenly stopped. Even OOTB workflows do the same thing. On another site collection they are still working. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you include what version of SharePoint you are using?

Comment: Hi, I'm using SharePoint 2013 and I'm using both 2010 and 2013 workflows. Same issue in each case.

Comment: Can you add that to your question so that others can use it to help you? You can click the edit button below your question.